# Signing Documents with itext 7 and GlobalSign's Document Signing Service (DSS)

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

Trying to create a Document Signing solution using iText7 & GlobalSign's DSS. Wanted to check if signing documents using DSS is supported in iText7. Is there a sample code that I can take a look at. Any information in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: *"Wanted to check if signing documents using DSS is supported in iText7."* - itext signing api is generic, not specific to any vendor. You implement an interface to connect the specific signing service of your choice.

Comment: did you get this to work? looking for a good example